# Trying to print integers and text using prinf in java

Tags: java, printf

```
if (num1 == 24 && num2 == 00) {
    System.out.printf( num1 + " " + "%02d%n", num2);
}
```

I'm trying print the following when this expression is true:

> 24 00 Midnight

The code above prints:

> 24 00

I've tried adding "Midnight" in the same line but this gives me an error.

Comment: "I've tried adding "Midnight" in the same line but this gives me an error." Show us how you tried to do so,

Answer (score 1):

You're completely missing the point of `String.format`. The point of it is to avoid manually formatting and concatenating strings representing elements, which you are doing anyway.

Since `if (num1 == 24 && num2 == 00)` must be true to be in that `if` block you can simply `System.out.println("24 00 Midnight");`.

Comment: Thanks for responding, the thing is, I have a number of different conditions that I want to meet i.e. add AM to times that are AM and PM to times that are PM. this is just my first shot at this one condition. The user should be able to put in any 24hr time and get the relevant output. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @JEarls In that case see the other answer by fuentesj; he gives the corrected format string.

Answer (score 0):

forgive my idiocy of coming at an irrelevant hour
System.out.printf("%d %d%d Midnight",x,y,y);